# Remove welcome page after going to another page

Tags: android, ionic-framework

In welcome page I use `this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);` As [official doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) says：

> They are destroyed when removed from the navigation stack (on pop() or
>   setRoot()).

welcome page should be removed, but when I press back button from HomePage on an android device , it always return Welcome page.
Why?

**Edited:**
I called the `setRoot` in wrong place as below

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
  setTimeout(() => {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
      }, 2000);
}
```

When I move it to `ionViewDidLoad`, it works well.

Comment: can you show the code where you have used this setRoot! because it should work

Comment: @Rizwanatta yes, it works normally, thank you reminding